# How many commands can you concatenate in a bash pipe?

Tags: bash, sed

I have to parse a file with many regular expressions. I would like to do that with a concatenation of sed 'replace' commands. So the question is how many sed commands, at maximum, i can concatenate in a bash pipe?

Comment: write `sed script` and pipe it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no limit on the number of pipes, as the commands are simply executed one after the other. The only limit would be the quantity of data passed in through the pipe, or the "Pipe Buffer Limit."

See here for more details: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer

Comment: There may be a `ulimit` in place to restrict how many concurrent processes you are allowed to start. Anyway, the better answer is that it can be done using only one process; see the discussion of @static_rtti's answer.

Comment: Pipes are not "executed one after another", but in parallel.

Comment: @static_rtti How is it possible for the pipes to work in parallel when they require the data from the previous command?

Comment: @ethanpil: because the data is not sent at once. The system starts all the commands, and sends data as it arrives (there might be some buffering, I don't know the specifics).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're asking this question shows that you're doing something wrong.

First, if you want to use a lot of regular expressions, as John has pointed, you can write a sed script. But why do you need so many regular expressions? Regexps are not the best match for all parsing tasks, writing an actual parser or using a parser generator could be far better solutions to your problem.

Comment: Interesting, but i must have the possibility of modifia ne number of regular exxpression in a brief time. I don't know how to do it in a different way.

Comment: @emanuele, instead of chaining multiple sed commands, use the `-e` option multiple times for one sed command.

Comment: @glenn jackmann: even better, use a script: `sed "s/a/b/;s/t/g/"` for example. If you have a lot of things to do, you can even put them in a file.

Comment: @static_rtti, some old seds don't understand `;` (such as the Solaris 8 system on which I work) so you're forced to use `-e`